# Freeswitch originate

Tags: python, sip, freeswitch

I'm using Freeswitch 1.6 ESL and when I place a call using API and remote IP Address I get:

**NO_ROUTE_DESTINATION**

```
2016-07-08 06:24:13.381491 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:296 No Dialplan on answered channel, changing state to HANGUP
```

It works fine If Im using a Phone registered to Freeswitch or instead of an IP I use a FQDN using SRV 5060 from my Service Provider.

```
2016-07-08 06:23:17.401446 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:300 No Dialplan, changing state to CONSUME_MEDIA
```

This is the command I'm using:

```
originate {origination_uuid=89f6f5d9-ab9f-4c12-80dd-46854ad8f80b,originate_timeout=18,origination_caller_id_number=+14082223333}sofia/external/99914081112222@1.1.1.1 & park()
```

**New channel**

```
2016-07-08 05:58:32.061466 [NOTICE] switch_channel.c:1104 New Channel sofia/external/99914081112222@1.1.1.1 [5a31b17e-2284-449e-bca0-d54f6bb5c35e]
```

**sofia global siptrace on**

```
2016-07-08 05:58:32.081459 [NOTICE] sofia.c:7968 Channel [sofia/external/99914081112222@192.241.203.21] has been answered
2016-07-08 05:58:32.081459 [DEBUG] switch_channel.c:3770 (sofia/external/99914081112222@192.241.203.21) Callstate Change DOWN -> ACTIVE
2016-07-08 05:58:32.081459 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_originate.c:3607 Originate Resulted in Success: [sofia/external/99914081112222@192.241.203.21]
2016-07-08 05:58:32.081459 [DEBUG] switch_ivr.c:2160 (sofia/external/99914081112222@192.241.203.21) State Change CS_CONSUME_MEDIA -> CS_ROUTING
2016-07-08 05:58:32.081459 [NOTICE] switch_ivr.c:2167 Transfer sofia/external/99914081112222@192.241.203.21 to park()[&@default]
2016-07-08 05:58:32.081459 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:543 (sofia/external/99914081112222@192.241.203.21) Running State Change CS_ROUTING
2016-07-08 05:58:32.081459 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:602 (sofia/external/99914081112222@192.241.203.21) State ROUTING
2016-07-08 05:58:32.081459 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:143 sofia/external/99914081112222@192.241.203.21 SOFIA ROUTING
2016-07-08 05:58:32.081459 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:236 sofia/external/99914081112222@192.241.203.21 Standard ROUTING
2016-07-08 05:58:32.081459 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:296 No Dialplan on answered channel, changing state to HANGUP
2016-07-08 05:58:32.081459 [NOTICE] switch_core_state_machine.c:298 Hangup sofia/external/99914081112222@192.241.203.21 [CS_ROUTING] [NO_ROUTE_DESTINATION]
```

**asterisk.xml**

```
<include>
        <gateway name="asterisk">
        <param name="proxy" value="1.1.1.1"/>
        <param name="register" value="false"/>
        <param name="outbound_caller_id_number" value="+14082223333"/>
        <param name="caller-id-in-from" value="true"/>
        </gateway>
</include>
```

**outboundcalls.xml**

```
<include>
<extension name="test">
        <condition field="destination_number" expression="^(999\d{11})$">
                <action application="set" data="effective_caller_id_number=1408222333"/>
                <action application="set" data="effective_caller_id_name=${outbound_caller_id_name}"/>
                <action application="bridge" data="sofia/gateway/asterisk/$1"/>
        </condition>
</extension>
<extension name="domestic">
        <condition field="destination_number" expression="^(\d{11})$">
                <action application="set" data="effective_caller_id_number=1408222333"/>
                <action application="set" data="effective_caller_id_name=${outbound_caller_id_name}"/>
                <action application="bridge" data="sofia/gateway/twilio/+$1"/>
        </condition>
</extension>
</include>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://www.mail-archive.com/freeswitch-users@lists.freeswitch.org/msg15454.html the issue was the space between & and park().